# Difference between pgf and pmf

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the difference between the probability generating function and probability mass function?

Answer (score 1):

The probability generating function only applies to discrete random variables. The probability density function applies to continuous random variables, it is the analog of the probability mass function for discrete random variables. Now in the case of a discrete random variable $X$ we have the probability mass function $p(x)$ which we can use to do things like calculate probabilities. One thing we can do with $p(x)$ is create the probability generating function $G(z)$. This is the power series $G(z)=\Sigma p(x) z^x$ where the sum is take over all possible values of the random variable $X$ and $z$ is a complex number.

Answer (score 0):

PGF- Power series representation of the so-called probability mass function of a discrete random variable.

So, if $X$ is a discrete random variable that takes values in non-negative integers $\{0,1,...\}$ the the PGF of $X$ is well defined as
\begin{eqnarray}
G(z) &=& E(z^{X}) \\
     &=& \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}p(x)z^{x}
\end{eqnarray}

PDF - An analogy for a continuous random variable exists and is the Probability Density Function. The probability density function $f_{x}$ of a (continuous) random variable $X$ is defined as;
$$P[a \leq X \leq b] = \int_{a}^{b}f_{X}dx. $$